# Difference between Xavier weights pytorch implementation

Tags: pytorch, initialization

What is the difference between nn.init.xavier_uniform and nn.init.xavier_uniform_ when initialising weights?

Answer (score 3):

The `_` convention in `nn.init.xavier_uniform_` is PyTorch's way of doing an operation in place. This convention applies to many of its functions.

Comment: `_` represents in place operation but not in case of `nn.init.xavier_uniform_` ,this is not in place operation...see my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

In latest pytorch version they both are the same , see [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/init.py#L518) for more detail .
in short i have small doc.

```
Signature: nn.init.xavier_normal(*args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
xavier_normal(...)

.. warning::
    This method is now deprecated in favor of :func:`torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_`.

See :func:`~torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_` for details.
```

Hence both are the **same**

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that they are the same. If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4bfe2a24505049fa4fe43d24c2e3a5f5d99d9f00/torch/nn/init.py#L557), you can see that `xavier_uniform` is defined as `xavier_uniform_`, but with deprecation warnings added.

I can't speak to *why* this change was opted for.